# Quadratic formula is wrong and I don't know how to fix

Tags: java, drjava

Errors:

```
File: F:\lab_2.java  [line: 36]
Error: next cannot be resolved or is not a field
File: F:\lab_2.java  [line: 38]
Error: next cannot be resolved or is not a field
File: F:\lab_2.java  [line: 40]
Error: next cannot be resolved or is not a field
File: F:\lab_2.java  [line: 42]
Error: Duplicate local variable outa
```

Code:

```
   else if (choice==1){
          int a;
          int b;
          int c;
          System.out.println("what is a ?");
          a=myscan.next ;   //line 36
          System.out.println("what is b ?");
          b=myscan.next ;   //line38
          System.out.println("what is c ?");
          c=myscan.next ;   //line40
       double outa =(b + Math.sqrt((b*b)-4*a*c))/(2*a);
       double outa =(b - Math.sqrt((b*b)-4*a*c))/(2*a);   //line42
       }
          //quadratic formula ^^^^
```

Comment: "and i don't know how to fix Drjava" Are you implying that your editor is broken?

Answer (score 1):

The error means that "next" is not a valid method or field on the variable myscan, which I assume is a Scanner.
if "myscan" IS a Scanner, I think you're looking for input, so:

```
a=myscan.nextInt();
```

Also, you assign b+ and b- to `outa`, so you're overwriting the first answer with the second.

Comment: do you know about File: F:\lab_2.java  [line: 42]
Error: Duplicate local variable outa

Comment: That's the last part of my comment, you declare and assign `double outa` twice.
You probably meant to do `outa` and `outb`?